# half_baddata function in c

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, decompiling

```
 **what this part of code means and do in c? I can't understand it!**
```

What's the return value of the if condition and when it will happened?

```
    LAB_001012c5
    if(local_10 != *(long*)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0*28)) {
    __stack_chk_fail();
    }
    void __stack_chk_fail(void){
    half_baddata()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you meant `0x28` not `0*28`.

The reverse compiler is having issues because this code can't be written in C. `in_FS_OFFSET` is the best representation that it can come up with for `[fs:28h]`.

This code is checking for a stack buffer overrun and faults execution before using the return address.